# How can i see my flutter app output in both Android and IOS simulator simultaneously?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, simulator

I am using the android studio to develop flutter application, I want to know is there any way I can see my app output in both android and ios simulator also I can perform hot reload on both simulator?

Answer (score 2):

To debug multiple devices concurrently you should set up a launch config for each device that has the deviceId fieldset (this is the same ID you'd pass to flutter run -d xxx). Open the launch config by clicking Debug -> Open Configurations. Add a compound config at the bottom that will launch both (or more) configurations at the same time:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Current Device",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Android",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "android"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "iphone"
        },
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "All Devices",
            "configurations": ["Android", "iPhone"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Selecting the compound config on the Debug side bar and clicking Debug -> Start Debugging (or Start Without Debugging) will launched debug sessions for each device at the same time.

Comment: More about this setup for multi-target debugging in VSCode in the [Flutter wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do that First install android and ios simulator and one by one `Flutter run` after that when both simulators are running. you can `Hot reload` from here.

[image]

and if you are looking for running both simultaneously then just then select all available devices and run your command. `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a command to run an app in both Ios and Android simulator.

write below command in a terminal **where your app is located**

```
flutter run -d all
```

You can press r keyword in terminal to do hot reload.

[image]